# Why does the active element have artifacts in firefox?

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar using a table, however in firefox the active/focused element has what looks kind of like back-tics (`` `) displayed on top of it (I think they are actually poorly rendered outlines):

[image]

Why are they there and how can I get rid of them?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2BEV/1/)

Comment: I do not see the reported issue in FF 26 or Chrome 32. (I think it looks like a duck.)

Comment: @user2864740 The above screenshot was taken in Firefox 27 on Linux.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Firefox 27 on Windows.

Comment: Unable to replicate on Firefox 25 on Mac. It might be your local font/rendering settings or something similar.

Comment: I can replicate on Firefox 27 on Ubuntu using the given JSFiddle page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rendering issue in Firefox: [#434301](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434301).

A comment by David Baron in Firefox Bugzilla clarifies the reason why it looks the way it is:

> What CSS says is that inlines that contain blocks get split into a
>   piece before the block and a piece after the block; you're seeing
>   the piece before the block get an outline around it.  That behavior
>   probably isn't ideal...

You can avoid this issue by avoiding having a `display:block` element that is directly inside a `display:inline`.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**:

A minimal test case reproducing the bug in my machine: http://jsfiddle.net/P2BEV/2/

[image]

Note that `<a>` is an inline element while `<div>` is a block element and an inline element cannot contain a block element for a valid HTML. The artefact itself is gone if the `<div>` is removed or if it is turned to `display: inline` with CSS, and it will show up if a `<span>` that have been turned to `display: block`. The artefact is also gone if you turned the add `display: block` to the `<a>`.

Experimenting a little more, it seems it's an issue whenever Firefox is drawing the outline for a `display:inline` element which contains a `display:block` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replicate this problem on another computer running linux and firefox. If it fails to, then it is an issue with your OS, browser or graphic settings.